# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: items.name

Tags: python, api, sqlite, fastapi

I am trying to build an API using FastAPI and store the database using sqlite but i am getting this error. I was unable to rectify this error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: items.name
[SQL: SELECT items.id AS items_id, items.name AS items_name, items.age AS items_age, items.sex AS items_sex, items.weight AS items_weight, items.nationality AS items_nationality, items.birth_type AS items_birth_type, items.smoking AS items_smoking, items.drinking AS items_drinking, items.history_of_ibd_in_family AS items_history_of_ibd_in_family 
FROM items]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

`code`

```py
@app.post('/')
class User(BaseModel):
    name:str
    age:int
    sex:str
    weight:int
    nationality:str
    birth_type:str
    smoking:str
    drinking:str
    history_of_ibd_in_family:str

def add_user_history(item:User):
    fakedata["name"] = item.name
    fakedata["age"] = item.age
    fakedata["sex"] = item.sex
    fakedata["weight"] = item.weight
    fakedata["nationality"] = item.nationality
    fakedata["birth_type"] = item.birth_type
    fakedata["smoking"] = item.smoking
    fakedata["drinking"] = item.drinking
    fakedata["history_of_inflammatory"] = item.history_of_ibd_in_family
    return fakedata

@app.get("/")
def getItems(session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    item = session.query(models.User_History).all()
    return item
```

`model.py`

```py
class User_History(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256))
    age  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sex  = Column(String(256))
    weight = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nationality = Column(String(256))
    birth_type = Column(String(256))
    smoking = Column(String(256))
    drinking = Column(String(256))
    history_of_ibd_in_family = Column(String(256))
```

can some one point out where i am doing wrong

Comment: The column `name` is not present in your `sqlite`-file; was it added to your model after the sqlite file was created? SQLAlchemy does not automagically add new columns to your database after you initialized the database with `.create_all` the first time.

Comment: I have added the name to my model after the sqlite file was created. once  i delete the database and recreated it. the error disappeared.

Comment: If you want to modify existing databases look into a proper migration tool. For SQLAlchemy that will usually be Alembic: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/